# how to add tabbar to uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tabbarcontroller

My app is  Navigation base application.In this application , UIViewController has button event  . Tap on Button firing to (pushViewController)  CalendarTableview. Now i need to add Tabbar and tabitem to calendartableview . how to add Tabbar and tabitem to CalendarTableview. help me .

here is my picture.[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UINavigationController has a built-in navigation-toolbar. Check [the section in appples developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), that should help if I understand your problem right.
[image: views]

Answer (score 1):

In your **calendartableview_controller**'s viewDidLoad() method, try to create a tab bar programmatically, and then add it as a subview to the **view** of your calendartableview_controller:

```
   //create a tab bar controller in your calendartableview_controller
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
   tabBarController.title = @"My Tab Bar";

   //assign child controllers to the tab bar controller
   tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController, nil];

   //add it to your calendartableview_controller's view as a subview
   [self.view addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```

Comment: @Rkm: the structure is totally up to you. As you can see, if you want one viewController to be **controlled** by the tab bar, that vc has be one of the tab bar's children. Back to your case, you may need to re-construct your UI structure so that such a tab bar can fit into your code.

Comment: i am following apple document, but all says that Darg down tabbar to main window of tabbarcontroller and give connection to navigation bar to tableview,i am little confusing. i am not getting , i posted my picture , i am not clear. please tell ,